Diagnosing an unexpected pattern in a survival curve plot
I am conducting a survival analysis (using Cox proportional hazards regression) in R. My overall sample has a ~10% mortality rate, but the Kaplan-Meier survival curves that are derived from my analysis appear to show a ~40-50% drop in survival, with a precipitous decline around the 4-year mark. This does not reflect the pattern of times to death in the actual dataset, but I am unsure what could be causing this discrepancy ... Does anyone have an idea?

# Define the strata for the plot
strata <- expand.grid(
  depression_level = levels(complete_cases_all$depression_level),
  sex = levels(complete_cases_all$sex)
  )
rownames(strata) <- letters[1:nrow(strata)]

# Define the average participant
average_participant <- expand.grid(
  depression_level = levels(complete_cases_all$depression_level),
  sex = levels(complete_cases_all$sex),
  calendar_year = median(complete_cases_all$calendar_year),
  age = median(complete_cases_all$age),
  education_level = median(complete_cases_all$education_level),
  employment = "Competitively Employed",
  marital_status = "Single",
  rehab_payor_primary_type = "Non-Medicaid",
  func_score = median(complete_cases_all$func_score),
  mental_health_tx_hx = 
    "Denied any history of mental health treatment",
  psych_hosp_hx = "Denied any history of psychiatric hospitalization",
  problematic_substance_use = "No",
  suicide_attempt_hx = "Denied any history of suicide attempt"
  )
rownames(average_participant) <- letters[1:nrow(average_participant)]

# Fit the survival model
cxsf <- survfit(model_5, newdata = average_participant, 
                conf.type = "none")
surv_cxsf <- surv_summary(cxsf, data = complete_cases_all) |>  
  # Summarize the survival model
  tibble()
m_newdat <- average_participant[as.character(surv_cxsf$strata), ]  
  # Match new data with survival summary strata

gg.surv.model5 <- surv_model_5 |>
  ggsurvplot_df(
    surv.geom = geom_line,
    color = "depression_level",
    xlab = "Time After X (years)",
    ylab = "Survival Probability",
    legend = c(0.175, 0.175),
    conf.int = FALSE,
    censor = FALSE,
    surv.scale = "percent",
    break.time.by = 1,
    xlim = c(0, 5), # Limit x-axis to 5 years
    ylim = c(crop, 1),
    palette = c("#90cbf9", "#2196f3", "#114b7a"),
    ggtheme = theme_classic(),
  ) +
  labs(linetype = "Sex", color = "Depression Level")

The data are based on a longitudinal dataset with follow-up interviews conducted at approximately 1 and 4 years after the initial study enrollment date. Dates of censorship were determined by the last available follow-up interview date for each censored participant, and dates of death were determined by the date listed in each decedent's official death certificate. Time 0 corresponds to the study enrollment date for each participant, with follow-up through the subsequent 5 years.
I've inspected the dataset for an abnormal count of decedents with deaths after the 4-year mark, but there appeared to be a reasonable frequency of deaths during this interval (~23% of the total deaths occurred between 4 and 5 years). I've ensured that my times to death are based on dates rather than (whole-number) follow-up intervals. Finally, I made sure that the censored participants are also contributing data within the 4-5-year window.

What is the size of your risk set at the end; how many observations end up censored? As the number of subjects at risk drops a single event can cause large jumps in the probability (because for example 1 out of 3 remaining experienced the event), it is quite common to truncate such curves at the point where 10-20% of your risk set remains if the majority of observations is being censored.

@PBulls The total number at risk is: 1,228 at 0 years; 1,153 at 1 year; 1,075 at 2 years; 1,052 at 3 years; 455 at 4 years; and 0 at 5 years.
Can you expand on what you mean by "it is quite common to truncate such curves at the point where 10-20% of your risk set remains"? Are you suggesting that I truncate the curves when the number at risk reaches 10-20% of the overall starting sample (i.e., the point when 128-245 participants [10-20% of 1,228] remain at risk)?

correct, this is a good reference that touches on some of these practices for displaying survival curves.

See also here: When presenting Kaplan-Meier figures, a good rule of thumb is to truncate follow-up when the number at risk in any group falls below 5 (or even 10) as the tail of a Kaplan-Meier distribution is very unstable.

The Kaplan Meier estimate is based on how many of the subjects that are still at risk have an event. If at the end only 2 are at risk, then one having an event means the survival curve goes down to 50% of where it was. You should be able to print out the number at risk & number with an event for each timepoint with an event. I'd guess you'd see that you are just having this sort of things happening towards the very end when very few are at risk. That's why it's sometimes recommended to cut-off the display of the curve once less than 10-15% are still at risk. Alternatively, you could estimate the survival curve assuming some parametric distribution, then this would also not happen.

The guidance to "cut-off the display of the curve once less than 10-15% are still at risk" seems to be quite common, according to the responses here. I've been reading up on survival analysis (particularly Cox regression) and have yet to come across this rule of thumb... Are you suggesting that I truncate the curves when the number at risk reaches 10-20% of the overall starting sample?

Yes, I've usually cited this paper for it: Pocock J, Clayton TC, Altman DG (2002) Survival plots of time-to-event outcomes in clinical trials: good practice and pitfalls. Lancet 2002; 359; 1686-89. doi: https://doi.org/10.1016/S0140-6736(02)08594-X
